# How to extract a WCS layer with gdal_translate?

Tags: gdal, wcs

There is a [certain](http://dmcsee.org/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/tmp/dmcsee_wms/dmcsee_wcs.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=DescribeCoverage&COVERAGE=SPI6) WCS layer that I'd like to save it to my local computer for analysis.

According to  GDAL WCS driver  [draft](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wcs.html):

"Accessing a WCS server is accomplished by creating a local service description xml file looking something like the following, with the coverage server url, and the name of the coverage to access. It is important that there be no spaces or other content before the  element.

```
<WCS_GDAL>
   <ServiceURL>http://laits.gmu.edu/cgi-bin/NWGISS/NWGISS?</ServiceURL>
   <CoverageName>AUTUMN.hdf</CoverageName>
</WCS_GDAL>
```

I tried to create the xml file but I was unsuccessful.

Does anyone has any experience about extracting WCS  layers? 
Are there any pointers (sites, tutorials, tips) on how to create the xml file?

**EDIT:**

The xml file im using to grab the first layer for a specific time is the following:

```
<WCS_GDAL>
   <ServiceURL>http://dmcsee.org/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/tmp/dmcsee_wms/dmcsee_wcs.map</ServiceURL>
   <Version>1.1.1</Version>
   <CoverageName>SPI6</CoverageName>
   <supportedCRSs>EPSG:4326</supportedCRSs>
   <PreferredFormat>gtiff</PreferredFormat>
   <GetCoverageExtra>&amp;BBOX=10.0,31.995,48.005,50.0&amp;time=19900101</GetCoverageExtra>
</WCS_GDAL>
```

But for somereason returns an error

Comment: Are you trying to automate the download? Because the data's available from website: http://www.dmcsee.org/en/drought_monitor/

Comment: Yes that's why I trying to use gdal_translate. I want to check how the index changes over a period of time.

Comment: What does `gdalinfo wcs.xml` return? I found that OWSLib (https://geopython.github.com/OWSLib) was very useful for accessing WCS'.

Comment: I didn't know about geopythons OWSlib. Sounds really promising I might be able to use that instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using python's OWSlib which was suggest by I was able to programmatically acquire the data.

Here's the script I used for future reference:

```
import os
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService as w  #owslib ->https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib
                                                #easy_install owslib

folder = 'c:\\path\\to\\folder\\'
wcs = w(url="http://dmcsee.org/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/tmp/dmcsee_wms/dmcsee_wcs.map",version="1.0.0")
spi6 = w['SPI6']  #The layer I am interested in 

for timep in spi6.timepositions :
   output = wcs.getCoverage('SPI6',time=[timep],bbox=(10.0,31.995,48.005,50),format='GTiff',CRS='EPSG:4326', WIDTH=380, HEIGHT=120)
   f = open(os.path.join(folder,'spi6_'+str(timep)+'.tiff'),'wb')
   f.write(output.read())
   f.close()
```

The above python script successfully downloaded and wrote 270+ geotiffs with their georeferenced data.

Comment: For some struggling with this, OWSLib doesn't seem to support all WCS protocols at the moment despite the documentation (e.g., 1.1.1)

Comment: @cefect will this approach bring original data or translate cell size etc If I use QGIS to extract data it changes cell size and hence raster does not snap to each other.