# How to automate downloading "slices" of data from Web Coverage Service (WCS)?

Tags: ogc, netcdf, wcs

I'd like to automate downloading "slices" of data from a WCS service. This is a WCS 1.1.2 service, supporting netCDF. The data are updated daily - forecasts from an atmospheric regional model - and I'd like to automatically download netCDF "slices" of the data for a fixed geographical bounding box and for a couple of days out into the future. I am quite happy processing the netCDF once I've downloaded it.

The obvious brute-force approach is to read the [OGC standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wcs) and devise the HTTP request myself, and code it up in some scripting language. I suspect I'll end up doing that. But it just feels *wrong*.

Can anyone recommend a WCS client library that I can use from code? Or a WCS client that I can run from a command-line? I know I could probably script QGIS or Grass or ArcGIS or something, but that seems too heavy a requirement for this task.

[Can GDAL do it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41123/how-to-extract-a-wcs-layer-with-gdal-translate)? Google has [turned up](https://sites.google.com/site/galeonteam/Home/GALEON%20WCS%20%22Tests%22) the BADC Python WCS library ([PDF](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https://ams.confex.com/ams/pdfpapers/150644.pdf&ei=qS2lUJqgKcec0QXclIHIBg&usg=AFQjCNEd3yGRVhCaYj3YG8Tr7mfQ7B7_kg)) (now in [OWSlib](http://geopython.github.com/OWSLib/)?) which I will take a look at. Java and [GeoTools](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/wcs/WCS.html) might be a possibility. And there's the OGC [list of WCS clients](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/1673) which I could trudge through.

This is on the Windows platform. A .Net library would be ideal :)

I haven't linked to the actual WCS service as it's not yet publicly operational. But here is an edited `GetCapabilities` request below, in case anyone's interested in the details

```
<Capabilities xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
  xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1"  
 version="1.1.2">  
<Contents>  
<CoverageSummary>  
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:2:84">  
<ows:LowerCorner>+0.0000 -90.0000</ows:LowerCorner>  
<ows:UpperCorner>+358.8750 +90.0000</ows:UpperCorner>  
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>  
<SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326</SupportedCRS>   
<SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:2:84</SupportedCRS>  
<SupportedFormat>image/netcdf</SupportedFormat>  
<SupportedFormat>application/x-netcdf</SupportedFormat>  
<Identifier>------------</Identifier> 
</CoverageSummary>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCS is the less-used of the WMS/WFS/WCS triangle so there isn't as much out there as you've probably noticed.

However, making requests is really *really* easy and you don't really need a special library. Arguably its the easiest of the three from a users perspective because you get a nice simple file back.

A valid request looks something like this:

`http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mywcs.map&SERVICE=wcs  &VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&coverage=bathymetry&CRS=EPSG:42304&OX=-2200000,-712631,3072800,3840000&WIDTH=3199&HEIGHT=2833&FORMAT=GTiff`

It may look complex, but broken down its very simple:

```
http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mywcs.map
&SERVICE=wcs
&VERSION=1.0.0
&REQUEST=GetCoverage
&coverage=bathymetry
&CRS=EPSG:42304
&BBOX=-2200000,-712631,3072800,3840000
&WIDTH=3199
&HEIGHT=2833
&FORMAT=GTiff
```

As you can see, most of them are self explanatory. So you just need to concatenate a string that has those variables. Most of them will probably be constants.

**Coverage** is the name of the layer you're requesting.

**BBOX** is the hardest part to do as you need to get the coordinates from somewhere.

I understand the point of libraries, but when something's this simple, "re-inventing the wheel" is actually a sensible option. You do of course need some sort of HTTP library.

A search for [WCS GetCoverage](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wcs%20GetCoverage) finds other examples. This page has a live example: http://www.mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html#test-your-wcs-1-0-server

Comment: +1 because I suspect this is exactly what I will do. I've done it before when I wanted to get images from a WMS.

Comment: Reporting back to say, yes, this is what I actually did...